Why is an imported variable reevaluated on each request in Flask?
I'm working on a flask app. There is the app.py file which uses an imported variable:
from other_file import rnd

@app.route('/some/path/', methods=['GET'])
def some_func:
    return make_response(jsonify(value=str(rnd)))

and other_file.py
import random

rnd = random.randint(100000, 1000000)

On each request, the returned value of the function is different. Why?
My desired behavior is that it returns the same value on each request.
What if I want to store some app-wide data in a variable, for example:
logged_in_users_list = []

Would that be emptied after each request too?
(Actually I use a similar approach in a FastAPI app, and the variable keeps the list fine. What makes the difference?)

Worth understanding How Are Requests Processed in Flask?

How is the app deployed?

@roganjosh apache2, wsgi

Are you running several processes? If so, each process will get its own value.

@M.O. There is this line in apache config: WSGIDaemonProcess app threads=5 . Does this mean 5 processes?
